# How to "trick" program installers so they will work on unsupported OS?

Tags: windows, version, legacy, nt

I want to install some software on a pre-alpha XP build (codename Windows Whistler). However, 90% of the installers fail to run. I guess it is because of the kernel version, which I suppose is somewhere between 5.0 and 5.1 (as I remember even the software that should run under Windsows 2000 did not succeed to install).

How can I most correctly and efficiently change the values in registry so that I have a chance to test some software (I know there can be bugs because of missing features, I'm doing tests in the VM).

The same question about Windows XP x64 with kernel version 5.2 - where to change it so that basic software designed for Win XP x86 does install as it does on regular Win XP (or maybe there is some compatibility option in properties).

Thanks for your help.

UPD: Java Runtime Environment version 5 update xxx should work on Windows 2000 (and even on Windows 98 SE, I tested it). But it somehow refused to install on Whistler... Maybe they cut something important away during development to make builds faster to compile?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Right Click on .exe -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Run this program in compatibilty mode for..` and then specify compatible versions of OS.

Comment: OK, that's about x64 (though I'm not sure it can mimic x86 version, I'll check). But what about Whistler? There is no "future" versions available in that list, of course. And I must mimic XP on the OS that is somewhere between Win2k and XP.